# In GCP, what is the smallest set of IAM roles that grant all permissions?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-iam

Per the title, what is the *smallest set* of IAM roles in GCP, set at the top-level org node, that grants *all* permissions over an entire organization hierarchy.

For example, a set containing `resourcemanager.folderCreator` and `resourcemanager.folderAdmin` would not be a smallest set, because the permissions comprising `resourcemanager.folderCreator` are contained in `resourcemanager.folderAdmin`.

For another example, the set `[resourcemanager.organizationAdmin, owner]` would not be a smallest set, because it does not grant *all* permissions (e.g. it is missing `orgpolicy.*`, among others).

What is it?

Comment: What is ALL? org and billing permission included? Or only project permissions?

Comment: Every permission there is.  Including billing, and so much more.

Comment: org admin role should be the highest. But it's against the least privilege principle. Use with caution.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand from the title of your question.
There isn't a role that grants all permissions.

You could consider using the organization admin role cause is the highest privilege to self assign permissions, is the only one that could grant you all the permissions.

Comment: that's right -- a single role doesn't include all permissions.  I'm looking for a _set_ of roles that together encompass all permissions.  But not just any set.  A smallest set.

Comment: You could use the next roles:
- org admin
- billing admin
- folder admin
- project owner
- Access Context Manager Admin
- Security Center Admin

This are the roles with the highest privileges that could give you the most permissions